# Horizontal Scroll on iOS — Off Canvas Navigation Menu

Tags: ios, css, menu, horizontal-scrolling

After pushing my site to the development server, I'm seeing horizontal scrolling on iOS (which I wasn't seeing when developing locally). I'm using an off canvas navigation menu which is giving the page the extra width. [Here is the site](http://development.infowest.com/infowest).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I inspected your site in Desktop Safari and I see the same issue.

The issue seems to be that the site layout still thinks it's wider. At first I was certain that a simple application of `overflow-x:hidden` and `width:100%` would do the trick.

However—

1. You seem to have done that.
2. It didn't.

I found it difficult to sift through the CSS because you have a lot going on, and I think it's possible that the CSS3 transforms are contributing to the issue, but I was able to lock it down while viewing in Desktop Safari and while [inspecting Mobile Safari directly](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) with the following:

- **Apply `position:fixed` to your primary navigation**, rather than `position:absolute`. Desktop Safari was happy with this.
- **Remove your `.site-content::before` pseudo-element.** This was still causing the issue on Mobile Safari. *Removing* the CSS transform to translate3d(100%,0,0) also helped.

Side note: You might also consider ways to simplify your HTML and/or CSS. You have 1.1MB loading without any real images; for mobile users, bandwidth is a real cost. I know that can be a PITA but worth mentioning. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this! I really appreciate you and the StackOverflow community. Thanks! What I did was, set `.nav-primary` to `position:fixed;` and `.site-content::before` to `position:fixed;` as well.

Comment: Glad it helped! And welcome to the SO community, from one relative newcomer to another...